# Implementing a Haversine function for sqlite into an iPhone project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, haversine

So after an hour of research, I've found that most people seem to agree that the function at http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71 is the way to go for implementing a Haversine function into an iPhone project for ordering results by distance when you have a database full of latitudes and longitudes. There seems to be little help on how to actually include it in your project though, and I'm having no luck on my own.

No matter where I add the function into my ViewController.m file, I get the error `expected ')' before '*' token`. Some people have mentioned you need to put `static void distanceFunc(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv);` into your .h file, but I get the same error there too.

Can anyone provide a brief example of including this function in an iPhone project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so my problem was a combination of not using `#import <sqlite3.h>` and not adding the `libsqlite3.0.dylib` framework to my project. As far as where to place the function from http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71, I put it between my `#import` tags and `@synthesize` in my controller's `.m` file, appearing just as it does in the blog post.

Answer (score 0):

your can use this,

```
+(void)distanceFunc(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv);
```

or change .m extention of your viewController file to .mm.(You can try this one also)

**updated**

```
+(void)distanceFunc:(sqlite3_context *)context arg1:(int)argc arg2:(sqlite3_value **)argv;
```

try updated one.

Thanks,

Comment: Sadly, if I put that into the header file, I get `error: expected ';' before '(' token`, and if I use that to replace the `static void distanceFunc(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)` line in my .m file for the function itself (after taking off the `;` on the end, of course), I get `error: expected '{' before '(' token`.

Comment: If I do this, I get these build errors related to the symbols `_sqlite3_value_type`, `_sqlite3_reset_null`, `_sqlite3_value_double`, and `_sqlite3_result_double`.

Comment: hav you added sqlite framework in your app. are you importing its header file?

Comment: one more thing have you tried with changing with extention of your file? from .m to .mm? is it working?

Comment: -1 sqlite3 doesn't know what an Objective-C method is.  There is no way you could pass it as an sqlite3 custom function.

Comment: please give some example for "There is no way you could pass it as an sqlite3 custom function."

Comment: It sounds weird to me too, but the post at http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71 does actually say "To use this function, add the code above to your Xcode project". So he makes it sound like you just add this into your project code and call it form there.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem with inserting the code in the link you gave anywhere in a `.m` file.  If you are getting the error on the function definition line, it is likely that the compiler doesn't know what an `sqlite3_context` is.  This means you haven't include the `sqlite3.h` header in your .m file.

Comment: The problem with that was that I hadn't added the `libsqlite3.dylib` framework to the project.